# Accessing file in firebase storage results in 403 ("The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account")

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm developing a Firebase Cloud Function that collects the metadata from a file stored in Firebase's Storage

My code is pretty much this:

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

exports.someFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    getMetadata("myBucket", data.filename)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("OK");
            return;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })

    // do some other stuff here ....

    return;
}

async function getMetadata(bucketName, filename) {
    const [metadata] = await storage
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .file(filename)
        .getMetadata();  <<== ERROR HAPPENS IN THIS CALL

    console.log(metadata.selfLink);
    console.log(metadata.size);
}
```

Whenever `storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename).getMetadata()` is called, as indicated in the code above, it results in a 403 with "The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account." I've tried running it both locally (with `firebase functions:shell`) and deployed. Here's the full error message:

```
{ Error: The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account.
    at Util.parseHttpRespBody (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:191:38)
    at Util.handleResp (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:135:117)
    at retryRequest (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:423:22)
    at onResponse (/srv/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:200:7)
    at /srv/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:222:13
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
  code: 403,
  errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'accountDisabled',
       message: 'The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account.',
       locationType: 'header',
       location: 'Authorization' } ],
  response: undefined,
  message: 'The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account.' }
```

That Firebase project has been on "Blaze plan" for a few weeks now and the billing account has been enabled for about a year, being charged for other GCP projects as well.

I've read the service account should have "signBlob" permission, which which I tried by adding "Service Account Token Creator" to both the default AppEngine Service Account and the Firebsae Service Account.

I've also tried initializing the storage via Firebase's admin SDK

```
const serviceAccount = require("path-to-json-downloaded-from-firebase-console.json");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://<my-project>.firebaseio.com"
});
const storage = admin.storage();
```

But no luck with either.

I couldn't figure out which account is 'disabled' or 'absent' nor what else I should configure to get this running and got stuck.

Any pointers that could get me troubleshoot further would help a lot.

Answer (score 7):

The cause was my misunderstanding of what "bucket" and "filename" are in the calls in the code.

In my case entering bucketName as `gs://[my-project].appspot.com` and fileName as the full path under the bucket fixed the issue.

More explicitly, the arguments should have been like:

```
const [metadata] = await storage
        .bucket("gs://[my-project].appspot.com")
        .file("path1/path2/actual-file-name")
        .getMetadata();
```